# How do I fix: Your app is sending Advertising ID over an unencrypted connection

Tags: android, admob

I'm in the middle of testing a beta apk so I'm uploading a new apk to the Play Store daily or every two days. Every so often (like 1 out of every 10) I will get a report from the Play Store that says "Your app is sending Advertising ID over an unencrypted connection."

I'm guessing this is a message about AdMob, which I do use however my AdMob is mediated through a different ad network. That might explain why the message doesn't show up every time.

How do I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: hi did you got any solution for the above issue?

Comment: No, and I still haven't figured out which ad network is doing it.

Comment: Turns out MoPub has a way to enable https. But I'm still getting that warning and have a few ad networks and I don't really know which one is doing it.

Comment: I think it might be Amazon. Their ad network seems to only send advertising id encrypted under iOS, not Android.

Comment: We are using Heyzap Ad intermediate that running ~8 Ads platforms, and having this too....

Comment: I'm almost certain it is Amazon. They started performing poorly so I removed them on my latest beta and after several releases I have yet to receive another warning.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ad network is passing your device's Advertising ID over a non-HTTPS connection.

You can proxy your device's connection and sniff the network requests to confirm, but I would see if there's a way to enable HTTPS for the requests, or ask the ad network to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the Amazon Ads library, but the warning only showed up after I updated to the latest library version 5.8.2. So I just reverted to the 5.4.78 library jar file and the problem appears to be gone.

Comment: For me it was Amazon as well.